# Why does Kernel#require raise a LoadError in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

Hi I have wondered for years why you can't use the `Kernel#require` method for loading gems.

For example this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
require 'ruby2d'    # => true
```

Here require's owner is Kernel:

```
p Object.method(:require).owner    # => Kernel
p Kernel.method(:require).owner    # => #<Class:Kernel>
```

But this works:

```
p Object.send :require, 'ruby2d'    # => true
p String.send :require, 'ruby2d'    # => false
p Kernel.require 'ruby2d'           # => false
```

or

```
gem 'ruby2d'                        # => true
p String.send :require, 'ruby2d'    # => true
p Kernel.require 'ruby2d'           # => false
```

[bad idea, but you can send the require method on any Object]

Somehow this doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
p Kernel.require 'ruby2d'
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from p.rb:2:in `<main>'
p.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- ruby2d (LoadError)
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s a couple of things going on here and interacting in interesting ways that we need to unpick to understand what’s happening.

First, how `require` works. There is a global variable `$LOAD_PATH` that contains a list of directories. The “original” way `require` worked (that is, without Rubygems), is Ruby will simply search this list for the required file and if it is found load it, otherwise it will raise an exception.

Rubygems changes this. When Rubygems is loaded it [replaces the built-in `require` method with its own](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L20-L133), aliasing the original first. This new method firsts calls the original, and if the required file is not found then instead of raising the exception immediately it will search the installed gems, and if a matching file is found then that gem is *activated*. This means (amongst other things) that the gem’s `lib` dir is added to the `$LOAD_PATH`.

Even though Rubygems is now part of Ruby and installed by default, it is still a separate library and the original code is still present. (You can disable loading Rubygems with `--disable=gems`).

Next, we can look at how the original `require` method is defined. It is [done with the C function `rb_define_global_function`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_3/load.c#L1234) . This function in turn [calls `rb_define_module_function`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_3/class.c#L1727-L1737), and that function [looks like](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_3/class.c#L1712-L1724):

```c
void
rb_define_module_function(VALUE module, const char *name, VALUE (*func)(ANYARGS), int argc)
{
    rb_define_private_method(module, name, func, argc);
    rb_define_singleton_method(module, name, func, argc);
}
```

As you can see, the method ends up being defined *twice*, once as a private method (that is the one included into `Object` and available everywhere), and once as a singleton method (that is, a class method) on `Kernel`.

Now we can start to see what’s happening. The Rubygems code only replaces the included version of `require`. When you call `Kernel.require` you get the original `require` method that doesn’t know anything about Rubygems.

If you run

```
p Kernel.require 'ruby2d'
```

you will get the same error as if you ran the following with Rubygems disabled (`ruby --disable=gems p.rb`):

```
p require 'ruby2d'
```

In both cases I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from p.rb:1:in `<main>'
p.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- ruby2d (LoadError)
```

This differs from if I run the second example *with* Rubygems, in which case I get (since I don’t have the gem installed):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from p.rb:1:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/matt/.rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/matt/.rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ruby2d (LoadError)
```

Both `LoadError`s, but one has gone through Rubygems and one hasn’t.

The examples where `Kernel.require` seem to work can also be explained, since in those case the file has already been loaded, and the original `require` codes simply sees an already loaded file and returns false. Another example where `Kernel.require` will also work would be

```
gem 'ruby2d'
Kernel.require 'ruby2d'
```

The `gem` method activates the gem, although it doesn’t load it. As described above this adds the gems lib dir (containing the file that is the target of the require) to the `$LOAD_PATH`, and so the original `require` code will find it and load it.

Comment: I perhaps should have added to this that you `require` a _file_, not a _gem_. Usually a gem has a “main” file with the same name as the gem itself, and the gem gets activated at the same time as the file gets required so this distinction is often lost, but is important for understanding the last example.

Comment: That's why: `Kernel.require 'bigdecimal'` returns `true`, while `Kernel.require 'ruby2d'` will raise `LoadError`

Comment: @S.Goswami yes, `bigdecimal` is included with Ruby and is already on the `LOAD_PATH`. (On my machine it is in `/Users/matt/.rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin17` which is on the `LOAD_PATH`). You don’t need to load any gems to use it.

Comment: Your answer is best. But just to give another example `$LOAD_PATH.map { |x| Dir.children(x) if File.directory?(x) }.flatten.compact.select { |x| /webrick.*|bigdecimal.*|ruby2d.+/i === x }` will return `["bigdecimal", "bigdecimal.rb", "webrick", "webrick.rb", "bigdecimal", "bigdecimal.so"]` and it will not include gems like 'ruby2d' or 'paint' or 'rainbow' ... So `Kernel.require` can only load what's there [as you told before] (even `Kernel.require 'bigdecimal.so'`) runs Ok!...