# What's the difference between Kernel.require and Kernel.gem_original_require?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

Consider the following script:

```
module Kernel
  unless defined?(gem_original_require_2)
    alias gem_original_require_2 require
    private :gem_original_require_2
  end

  def require(path)
      return gem_original_require_2(path)
  end
end

p method(:require)                  # #<Method: main.require>
p method(:require).owner            # Kernel
p method(:require).receiver         # main
p method(:require).source_location  # ["1.rb", 7]

puts '-' * 10
p Kernel.method(:require)                  # #<Method: Kernel.require>
p Kernel.method(:require).owner            # #<Class:Kernel>
p Kernel.method(:require).receiver         # Kernel
p Kernel.method(:require).source_location  # nil

puts '-' * 10
p Kernel.method(:gem_original_require)                  # #<Method: Kernel.gem_original_require(require)>
p Kernel.method(:gem_original_require).owner            # Kernel
p Kernel.method(:gem_original_require).receiver         # Kernel
p Kernel.method(:gem_original_require).source_location  # nil

puts '-' * 10
p Kernel.method(:gem_original_require_2)                  # #<Method: Kernel.gem_original_require_2(require)>
p Kernel.method(:gem_original_require_2).owner            # Kernel
p Kernel.method(:gem_original_require_2).receiver         # Kernel
p Kernel.method(:gem_original_require_2).source_location  # ["/home/yuri/.rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb", 34]
```

I've got a lot of questions about the output. Why is `Kernel` sometimes a class, sometimes a module? Why do they have different receivers? Does `receiver` become `self` when method gets called?

But more importantly, are `Kernel.require` and `Kernel.gem_original_require` the same method? Is there another place where `Kernel.require` [gets overridden](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v3.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L34)? If you can answer the rest of the questions, that would be awesome.

---

Let me put it another way. Let's try to reproduce this issue with run-of-the-mill classes and methods. As stated in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57236134/52499) defining a method on `Kernel` creates 2 methods (instance and singleton). So:

```
class MyKernel
  # original require
  def require; puts 'require'; end
  def self.require; puts 'require'; end

  # copy original require
  alias gem_original_require require
  class << self
    alias gem_original_require require
  end
end

main = MyKernel.new
```

`Kernel` is in fact a module, but supposedly that doesn't matter here.

```
p MyKernel.method(:require)
  == MyKernel.method(:gem_original_require)
  # true

p main.method(:require)
  == main.method(:gem_original_require)
  # true

p main.method(:require)
  == MyKernel.method(:require)
  # false
```

So, supposedly to compare methods you've got to access them both either via a class, or via an instance. Let's override `require`:

```
class MyKernel
  # override one of the original require's
  def require; puts 'require'; end
end
```

Now we've got 3 `require`s:

```
main.require (original)
MyKernel.require
main.require
```

and 2 `gem_original_require`s:

```
main.gem_original_require
MyKernel.gem_original_require
```

We can compare like with like (instance methods with instance methods, singleton with singleton). But we no longer have access to the original `main.require`, so that leaves only singleton methods. And the following still holds:

```
p MyKernel.method(:require)
  == MyKernel.method(:gem_original_require)
  # true
```

But not in case of the real `require`:

```
p Kernel.method(:require)
  == Kernel.method(:gem_original_require)
  # false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid ambiguity I'm going to call methods owned by singleton classes singleton methods, the rest are instance methods.

```
class A
    def m; end       # instance method
    def self.m; end  # singleton method
end
```

(Although one might say that a singleton method is an instance method of the corresponding singleton class.)

One might call singleton methods class methods, but that would be oversimplification. Objects can also have singleton methods:

```
a = A.new
def a.m2; end
p a.singleton_methods(false).include? :m2                 # true
p a.singleton_class.instance_methods(false).include? :m2  # true
```

Instance methods are often called via an instance of a class/module (e.g. `[].compact`, `compact` is owned by the `Array` class). But not necessarily so (an example is one of the reasons which led to me creating the question). What adds to the confusion are the `methods`/`instance_methods` methods. `A.methods` returns singleton methods of the object `A`, and `A.new.instance_methods`... is unavailable. So generally you want to call `methods` on an instance of a class, and `instance_methods` on a class/module, but... that depends. For those willing to understand this better I suggest [these](https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/demystifying-singleton-classes-in-ruby-caf3fa4c9d91) two [links](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/69c48ac5c3af0c1d3b11dc9a7f541f92).

Now, as stated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235261/why-does-kernelrequire-raise-a-loaderror-in-ruby/57236134#57236134) suggested by Gimmy, `require` is a [global function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/load.c#L1234). Which means that it's [defined](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/class.c#L1740-L1750) as [both](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/class.c#L1725-L1737) a `Kernel`'s private instance method, and a `Kernel`'s singleton method.

```bash
$ ruby --disable-gems -e 'p [
  Kernel.private_instance_methods(false).include?(:require),
  Kernel.singleton_class.instance_methods(false).include?(:require),
  Kernel.instance_method(:require) == Kernel.singleton_class.instance_method(:require)
]'
[true, true, false]
```

Which means that you can call it basically from anywhere with `require` as an instance method (since almost all the objects are inherited from `Object`, and `Kernel` is [included](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/object.c#L4147-L4158) into `Object`):

```
require 'time'
```

Alternatively, you can call it (the other instance of the method) with `Kernel.require` as a singleton method:

```
Kernel.require 'time'
```

That, in its turn, means that `rubygems` create an [alias](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v3.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L16) of only the private instance method `require`.

About the second part:

```
class MyKernel
  # original require
  def require; puts 'require'; end       # (1)
  def self.require; puts 'require'; end  # (2)

  # copy original require
  alias gem_original_require require    # (3)
  class << self
    alias gem_original_require require  # (4)
  end
end

main = MyKernel.new

class MyKernel
  # override one of the original require's
  def require; puts 'require'; end
end

p MyKernel.method(:require)
  == MyKernel.method(:gem_original_require)
  # true
p Kernel.method(:require)
  == Kernel.method(:gem_original_require)
  # false
```

`r.method(:m)` returns the method that would be called if you called `r.m`.
As such `MyKernel.method(:require)` refers to the singleton method of the `MyKernel` class (2).
And `MyKernel.method(:gem_original_require)` refers to its alias (4).

In the second statement `Kernel.method(:require)` refers to the singleton method of the `Kernel` module. But `Kernel.method(:gem_original_require)` refers to an [alias](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v3.0.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L16) of the private instance method of the module `Kernel`. That is, the `Kernel` module itself doesn't have a singleton method `gem_original_require`, but since `Kernel` is also an object, and `Object` has a private instance method `gem_original_require` (included from the `Kernel` module), that is what is returned by `Kernel.method(:gem_original_require)`:

```
p \
  Kernel.singleton_class
    .instance_methods(false).include?(:gem_original_require),
    # false
  Kernel.singleton_class
    .private_instance_methods(false).include?(:gem_original_require),
    # false
  Kernel.class.ancestors,
    # [Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
  Kernel.private_instance_methods(false).include?(:gem_original_require)
    # true
```

To make it close enough to what happens with `require`:

```
module Kernel
  def m; end
  private :m
  def self.m; end
  alias malias m
end
p Kernel.method(:m) == Kernel.method(:malias)  # false
```

About the first part:

```
def pmethod n, m
  puts n + ': ' + m.inspect
  puts '  owner: ' + m.owner.inspect
  puts '  receiver: ' + m.receiver.inspect
  puts '  source_location: ' + m.source_location.inspect
end
def hr
  puts '-' * 3
end

module Kernel
  unless defined?(gem_original_require_2)
    alias gem_original_require_2 require
    private :gem_original_require_2
  end

  def require(path)
      return gem_original_require_2(path)
  end
end

pmethod 'require', method(:require)
pmethod 'Kernel.require', Kernel.method(:require)
pmethod 'Kernel.gem_original_require', Kernel.method(:gem_original_require)
pmethod 'Kernel.gem_original_require_2', Kernel.method(:gem_original_require_2)
```

Let me first say a couple of words about the way `ruby` outputs objects:

```
p Object      #=> Object
p Object.new  #=> #<Object:0x000055572f38d2a0>
p Kernel      #=> Kernel
```

In case of singleton classes the output is [of the form](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_10/object.c#L1781):

```
#<Class:original_object>
```

Given a singleton class `S`, `original_object` is an object such that `original_object.singleton_class == S`.

```
p Kernel.singleton_class      #=> #<Class:Kernel>
p Object.new.singleton_class  #=> #<Class:#<Object:0x000055cad6695428>>
```

Instances of `Method`/`UnboundMethod` are output this way:

```
#<Method: receiver(owner)#method(original_method)>
```

`r.method(:m)` returns the method that would be called if you did `r.m`. `r` is the receiver, `m` is the method. Depending on the type of the method (singleton/instance) the `receiver` in the output means different things: for instance methods it's the class of the receiver, for singleton methods the receiver itself. `owner` is the class/module that owns the method (the class/module `o` such that `o.instance_methods(false).include?(:m) == true`):

```
class A
  def m; end  # owner is A
              # A.instance_methods(false).include?(:m) == true
  def self.m; end  # owner is the singleton class of A
                   # A.singleton_class
                   #  .instance_methods(false).include?(:m) == true
end
```

If an owner is a singleton class, its original object is displayed (an object `o` such that `o.singleton_class == owner`).

When the receiver and the owner match, the owner is not duplicated in parenthesis.

If the method is an alias, then the original method is specified in parenthesis.

`.` is used in place of `#` for singleton methods (methods owned by singleton classes).

Now the output should be self-explanatory:

```
require: #<Method: Object(Kernel)#require>
  owner: Kernel
  receiver: main
  source_location: ["a.rb", 17]
```

An instance method (owned by the `Kernel` module), the receiver is `main` (of the `Object` class).

```
Kernel.require: #<Method: Kernel.require>
  owner: #<Class:Kernel>
  receiver: Kernel
  source_location: nil
```

A singleton method (owned by the singleton class of the `Kernel` module), the receiver is `Kernel`. Considering that the owner is a singleton class, its original class (`Kernal`) is taken for the `owner` part. And since the resulting owner and receiver are both `Kernel`, the name is not duplicated.

```
Kernel.gem_original_require: #<Method: Module(Kernel)#gem_original_require(require)>
  owner: Kernel
  receiver: Kernel
  source_location: nil
Kernel.gem_original_require_2: #<Method: Module(Kernel)#gem_original_require_2(require)>
  owner: Kernel
  receiver: Kernel
  source_location: ["/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb", 34]
```

These two are aliases of the method `require`. They are instance methods, which means the originals are also instance methods. The receiver is `Kernel` (of the `Module` class). The owner is `Kernel`.

To answer the rest of the question:

> Why is Kernel sometimes a class, sometimes a module?

`#<Class:Kernel>` is the `ruby`'s way of outputting a singleton class of `Kernel`.

> Why do they have different receivers?

The receiver is the object whose method is being called. If the receiver is specified explicitly (e.g. `Kernel.require`), it's the object before the dot. In other cases it's `self`. And at the top level `self` is the `main` object.

> Does a receiver become self when a method gets called?

Supposedly yes.

> are `Kernel.require` and `Kernel.gem_original_require` the same method?

No, the first one is the `Kernel`'s singleton method (an instance method of the `Kernel`'s singleton class), the second one is a private instance method of the `Kernel` module.

> Is there another place where Kernel.require gets overridden?

Not that I know of.

> So, supposedly to compare methods you've got to access them both either via a class, or via an instance.
> We can compare like with like (instance methods with instance methods, singleton with singleton).

They must refer to the same instance of a method, and the receivers must match:

```
class A
  def m; end
  alias ma m
end
class B < A; end
a = A.new
b = B.new
p a.method(:m) == a.method(:ma)                   #=> true
p a.method(:m) == b.method(:m)                    #=> false
  # receivers do not match
p A.instance_method(:m) == B.instance_method(:m)  #=> false
  # receivers do not match
p a.method(:m) == A.instance_method(:m)           #=> false
  # #<Method:...> can't be equal #<UnboundMethod:...>
```

The issue with `Kernel.method(:require) != Kernel.method(:gem_original_require)` is that they belong to different classes/modules (`Kernel.singleton_class` and `Kernel`), although the receivers and method definitions match.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find part of the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57236134/6008847

Rubygems code replaces the included version of `require`.

When you call `Kernel.require` you get the original require method.

When you cal `require` you get the method from Rubygems (the receiver will be the context from where you call `require`).

`gem_original_require` is an alias for the original `require` method: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_3/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L16

Comment: Your answer indeed clarifies some issues, but not all (or most) of them. See my updated question (after hr). And yes, receiver is what becomes `self` when you call a method.

Comment: I've been digging into singleton classes, method lookup, class/instance eval, the main object, you name it. Particularly I've answered this question. You can [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75077722/52499) if you want. It feels like I finally understood how it all works. Well, at least the class-related stuff. And a [couple](https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/demystifying-singleton-classes-in-ruby-caf3fa4c9d91) of [related](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/69c48ac5c3af0c1d3b11dc9a7f541f92) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917811/what-is-main-in-ruby/75066706#75066706).